# LOOCV $R^2$ higher than regular $R^2$ in RF

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, r-squared, caret

I am working with RF and the caret package, and I am having a confusion because sometimes the LOOCV $R^2$ is higher than the regular $R^2$. Is it right? How can I interpret this?

Here an example using airquality data in R

```
library(caret)
data(airquality)
data <- airquality[complete.cases(airquality), ]
O<-data$Ozone
    Predictors<-cbind(data$Solar.R,data$Wind,data$Temp)
set.seed(6)
fitControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV",returnResamp="final")
rfGrid = expand.grid(.mtry = 1:3 )
rfFit_O = train(Predictors,O, "rf", tuneGrid = rfGrid, trControl = fitControl)
rfFit_O
```

Here the model shows me a LOOCV $R^2$ of 0.7374755 with optimal Mtry=2

```
rfFit_O$finalModel
    Obs<-O
    Pred<-predict(rfFit_O$finalModel)

regular.R2<-1 - sum((Obs-Pred)^2)/sum((Obs-mean(Obs))^2)
regular.R2
```

When I calculate the regular $R^2$ the result is 0.7334154, a slightly smaller value.

I want to present the regular $R^2$ and the LOOCV $R^2$ in a publication, and this doesn't make any sense to me. Must I calculate LOOCV $R^2$ using another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your script and ran into a couple of things:

1. I actually got a value of 0.7335533 for LOOCV R2 and 0.7377932 for the full dataset predict function, so you might want to double-check your answers just in case.
2. The caret.train function seeks to minimize RMSE by default and you did not specify your own parameter. R2 might not follow the expected pattern in this case, but I found an RMSE of 16.96241 for the final model vs. 17.10235 during cross-validation; I recommend you check yours too.

As a final note, if you wish to present your results as a measure of model predictive power, I would highly recommend setting aside a test set prior to conducting CV. The final model is trained on the entire set otherwise and model fit stats may be overly optimistic unless evaluated on a completely unseen test set. This might not be a big issue for certain problems, but you may suffer a massive disappointment in other cases and I can atest to that from personal experience.

You can certainly then use the full dataset to train a "production-ready" model, but the model accuracy estimates should still be the ones you obtained on your unseen test set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The R2 results vary because of the randomness in RF. And they still are very close (regular and LOOCV R2)

Comment: @JulianCabezasPeña wasn't specifying a seed meant to take care of that or would that only apply to the CV partitioning?

Comment: Also, the greater the number of CV folds, the closer the CV model fit will be to the one obtained when predicting on the full training set; LOOCV has the maximum number of folds possible.

Comment: My problem is that i dont have enough data to split the in train/test, so I want to perform CV

Comment: I've seen the dataset and I agree that it is quite small. But because it is small, you might want to consider embedded cross-validation methods, as the computational cost should not be an issue and you'd still be able to get some of the benefits of using a test set. Ultimately, CV is intended more for parameter optimization and assessment than predictive power assessment of a final model.

Comment: glad to hear it.